# Eliminate or translate HTML character in SQL import from XML file

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I came across an issue when running a procedure that shreds an XML file and imports the data into SQL server.

It has been running successfully for a few months, but today I got an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

This is the line where it fails

```
SELECT 
ltrim(rtrim(T.X.value('Cell[4]/Data[1]','varchar(max)'))) AS StartDate
,ltrim(rtrim(T.X.value('Cell[5]/Data[1]','varchar(max)'))) AS EndDate
FROM @xml.nodes('/Workbook[1]/Worksheet1]/Table[1]/Row') as T(X)
```

When I looked at the XML file, I noticed that some of the dates were written like this:

> 01/12/2016&#160

This character `&#160` is a [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

I would like to know if there is any way in SQL Server to account for these types of issues? For this specific problem, I can use `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(ltrim(rtrim(T.X.value('Cell[4]/Data[1]','varchar(max)'))),'&#160','') AS StartDate
,ltrim(rtrim(T.X.value('Cell[5]/Data[1]','varchar(max)'))) AS EndDate
FROM @xml.nodes('/Workbook[1]/Worksheet1]/Table[1]/Row') as T(X)
```

but if other XML/HTML characters come up, is there a way to universally check for/deal with them?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't. This is a problem of generating the XML actually. The check for data consistency and data type integrity should be done there. Regrettfully quite often one can find XML which is not properly generated but rather "string buildered" directly out of user's input.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you could create an auxiliary table of strings that you wish to replace/remove and join that to your query. This would be preferred over hard-coding each character, and would allow you to expand on the functionality easily. The caveat is that I'd expect it to slow down you query based on the number of characters you need to replace/remove.

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(ltrim(rtrim(T.X.value('Cell[4]/Data[1]','varchar(max)'))),
          StringsToRemove.string,'') AS StartDate,
  REPLACE(ltrim(rtrim(T.X.value('Cell[5]/Data[1]','varchar(max)'))),
          StringsToRemove.string, '') AS EndDate
FROM
  @xml.nodes('/Workbook[1]/Worksheet1]/Table[1]/Row') as T(X),
  StringsToRemove
```